# How to generate UML package diagram with nested packages which may contain same names in different level?

Tags: package, plantuml

I want to generate a package diagram with hierarchical packages which may contain duplicated names but not in the same level. e.g.:

```
@startuml
package A {
    package B {
        package C
    }
    package A
}
@enduml
```

I think, `package A.A` might be acceptable. But `plantuml` failed with this error: `Thie element (A) is already defined`.

I also try the following:

```
@startuml
folder A {
    folder B {
        folder C
    }
    folder A
}
@enduml
```

Then, `plantuml` failed with the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw diagrams with duplicated names if you include non-printing characters in the definition, e.g. by putting the name in quotes and including one or more space characters:

```
@startuml
package A {
    package B {
        package C
    }
    package "A "
    package "A  "
}
@enduml
```

The additional spaces do not affect the layout in the diagram:

[image: UML class diagram with duplicated packages]

Answer (score 8):

One of the options :

```
@startuml
package A as pkg0{
    package B as pkg1{
    }
    package A as pkg2{
        package A as pkg3{
        }
    }
    package A as pkg4{
    }
}
@enduml
```

will give result

[image]